# How can I change a caret right to a caret down when clicking on it to open sub-menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a nav-bar with a sub-menu.
I have only a member with a caret close by, when I click on it I open the sub-menu with the other members. But the caret remains to the right. I need to change it to the down when the sub-menu is open, and to the right when it's closed.
Do I have to use jQuery? How?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? If you look at the code that creates the down-caret, then you'll be able to create a right facing one...

Comment: Yes, add/remove applicable classes on the element in question when the click event, to open the sub-menu, is fired.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Comment: Please add demonstration code for your attempts thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery `addClass` and `removeClass` you can remove a class and add a new class like:

```
$('btn').click(function(){
  $('selector').removeClass('caret-right').addClass('caret-down');
});
```

where `caret-right` is a css selector that contains the css to show caret in right direction and same for `caret-down`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use classes, you can just rotate the whole thin:

```
$('btn').click(function(){
      $("#caret").css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + 90 + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

And yes, I would use JQuery for that

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery toggleClass to achieve this

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('down');
});
```

```css
.down i{
transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button>
<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
</button>
```